# while starting business network in hyper ledger composer i am getting below error

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-composer

```
Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message:  is not a valid endorsement system chaincode)
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message:  is not a valid endorsement system chaincode)
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message:  is not a valid endorsement system chaincode)
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message:  is not a valid endorsement system chaincode)
Command failed
```

please help me resolve this error in composer .

Answer (score 1):

This error is normally seen when you have Composer v0.20 and are trying to work with Fabric 1.1.  For Composer v0.20 you need to be working with Fabric 1.2 or Fabric 1.2.1.  [This document shows](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/releases) the releases of Composer and the Compatible Fabric versions.

If you need detailed instructions to remove Fabric 1.1 and Install Fabric 1.2.1, then one of the [comments in this issue](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4305) covers the steps.

Comment: its only getting in multi organisation network ,this type of error is not getting in single organisation ,can you tell me why it is only in multi organisation network .

Comment: I would guess that you have Downloaded 2 versions of Fabric - 1.1 and 1.2 .  When you run the Single-Org tutorial you are using Fabric 1.2, and when you run the Multi-Org you are running 1.1.  - Perhaps you are looking at a v0.19 version of the tutorial document? or Perhaps you have upgraded Composer to v0.20 recently?

Comment: my composer version is 20.0 and my fabric version is 1.2 ,still it is not working on it.

Comment: could you tell me ,how to see fabric version in linux , i am able to see composer version ,i am not able see fabric version in linux,please tell me how to get fabric version.

Comment: The command `docker images` will show you all the Docker Images you have downloaded, and the versions should appear as "tags".  It is possible you have more than one version downloaded.  Maybe you would be best to remove all Containers and all Images and then carefully follow the Multi-Org tutorial, making sure you are looking at the "latest" version of the tutorial (not the v0.19 version) https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org

Comment: do you know how to add multiple channels and  ledgers using hyper-ledger composer,also can we create separate ledger for each participant in business network,If you know please help us on this.